# Initialize a class property

Tags: php, class

Is there a way to initialize a PHP class property from another class property? I have a series of properties I'd like to depend upon each other for easy modification of the root value:

```
class Anon {
    private static $a = 5;
    private static $b = '+' . (2 * self::$a);
}
```

However, this causes a syntax error. I've had trouble searching for this, but I haven't seen anybody trying to do this!

Comment: You can not have operators and function calls in property declaration, you will have to solve this with class methods. PHP manual: "This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value" - http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialise the static variable by using an Init method

```
   <?php
    class Anon {
        private static $a = 5;
        private static $b ;
        public static function Init(){
            self::$b = '+' . (2 * self::$a);
        }
        public static function getB(){
            return self::$b;
        }
    }
    Anon::Init();
    echo Anon::getB();
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I chose this because it has the combination of one-time init, and the getter function. Will be helpful for others down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you're using the class, but maybe this will help:

```
class Anon {
    private static $a = 5;
    private static $b;

    function __construct() {
        self::$b = '+' . (2 * self::$a);
    }

    public function getB() {
        return self::$b;
    }
}

$anon = new Anon;
echo $anon->getB();
```

Comment: with this solution, `$b` will be initialized each time that an object will be created, and it is wrong !!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately PHP can not parse non-trivial expression while class is being loaded
Here is a solution to initialize your static members

```
    class Anon {
      private static $a;
      private static $b;

    public static function init () {
        self::$a = 5;
        self::$b = '+' . (2 * self::$a);
    }
   }

Anon::init();
```

Comment: there is no `void` in PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can't access private class properties directly. You can with public though.

```
class Anon {
    public static $a = 5;
}

print Anon::$a;
```

or use a public function like the other examples to access `$b`;

```
class Anon {

    private static $a = 5;
    private static $b;

    public static function init() {
        return self::$b = '+' . (2 * self::$a);
    }
}

echo Anon::init();
```